# Reading utf8-encoded data from a connection, using Go

Tags: utf-8, go

I can easily write a string to a connection using io.WriteString.

However, I can't seem to easily *read* a string from a connection. The only thing I can read from the connection are bytes, which, it seems, I must then somehow convert into a string.

Assuming the bytes represent a utf8-encoded string, how would I convert them to string form?

(Edit: alternatively, how could I simply read a string from a connection?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cast a slice of bytes into a string:

```
var foo []byte
var bar string = string(foo)
```

There is no encoding/decoding involved, because strings are just treated as arrays of bytes.

Comment: That's not 100% true, though close enough. Strings are treated differently than byte-arrays.

Comment: Just curious, how to check when end of string (or end of char) reached? Or can I read char by char (using cast) to build the string from the connection?

Answer (score 4):

A handy tool that will suit your purpose can be found in the standard library: `bytes.Buffer` ([see the package docs](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)).

Say you have an object that implements `io.Reader` (that is, it has a method with the signature `Read([]byte) (int, os.Error)`).

A common example is an `os.File`:

```
f, err := os.Open("/etc/passwd", os.O_RDONLY, 0644)
```

If you wanted to read the contents of that file into a string, simply create a `bytes.Buffer` (its zero-value is a ready-to-use buffer, so you don't need to call a constructor):

```
var b bytes.Buffer
```

Use `io.Copy` to copy the file's contents into the buffer:

```
n, err := io.Copy(b, f)
```

(An alternative to using `io.Copy` would be `b.ReadFrom(f)` - they're more or less the same.)

And call the buffer's String method to retrieve the buffer's contents as a string:

```
s := b.String()
```

The `bytes.Buffer` will automatically grow to store the contents of the file, so you don't need to worry about allocating and growing `byte` slices, etc.